# Determine using directives of an assembly

Tags: .net

When i load a dll into my program in .NET 6 like that

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("my.dll");
Type[] exportedTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

Is there a way to determine which using directives the dll uses?

Comment: Using directives are a C# thing, they don't exist in the compiled assembly. And even if they did, they're per-file, not per-assembly. Why do you need that information?

Comment: Oh thank you. Its because i wrote a plugin system for an application and tried to implement a security thing to determine if a plugin uses specific namespaces. For e.g if a plugin writes to the file system or connects over the network.

Comment: If you're concerned about that, run the plugin in a virtual machine. Depending on namespaces is a bad idea.

Comment: How do you mean "run the plugin in a virtual machine"? Literally? I just thought about if they load a plugin (a dll) they will have a small label in the UI or an inspector window which states what capabilities a plugin has.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing using directives (a short hand for not having to spell out the full namespace name when referring to a type in a file) with references (which tell you which assemblies a particular assembly depends upon). They are orthogonal concepts. In particular, you can use types from a referenced assembly without ever having to include any particular namespaces in any using directives.